# Book suggestions to learn more about Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, euler-mascheroni-constant

I want to learn more about the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\gamma$ and do research on a problem related to it. The problem does not necessarily has to be the question of rationality/irrationality of $\gamma$ but rather can be a different one that is yet unanswered. But I am interested only in pure/Theoretical questions regarding $\gamma$ rather than computational or applied ones.

But in general, which branch of mathematics studies this constant and its characteristics? Is it Number Theory(or a specific sub-branch of it)? But I have not studied Number Theory since there is no such course in my college.

Can someone tell me which branch of Mathematics studies it and what could be some good books to get started and reach up to an intermediate/advanced level so that I can carry out some real research in this field.

Comment: There is a whole book about this constant, containing all the basics - this would be a good place to start. 'Gamma' by Julian Havil, Princeton University Press.

Comment: @ThomasBloom := Thank you for your comment. I'll definitely look into this book. But can you also tell which field of Mathematics actually studies this constant and its characteristics? Because, if I were to do research, I must know enough in that field too.

Comment: The main topic is analytic number theory, but one would also need a good understanding of both real and complex analysis.

Comment: There's no specific field of Mathematics that studies the constant. The constant appears in several fields of Mathematics naturally. Depending on the aspect you are interested, it could be Analysis, Analytic Number Theory, Trascendental Number Theory, Numerical Analysis, Computability Theory, ...

Comment: @ThomasBloom := Thanks again! I know books on analysis. Can you also suggest me a good book on Analytic Number Theory? Also, I assume that Analytic Number Theory assumes knowledge of General/Elementary Number Theory . (Am I correct?)

Comment: @jjagmath := Yes, I know there isn't a specific field that solely studies it. But I wanted to at least know which ones do. And if this helps to shorten the list of fields, I am interested only in pure/Theoretical questions regarding $\gamma$ rather than computational or applied ones.

Comment: See also the book https://www.cambridge.org/br/academic/subjects/mathematics/recreational-mathematics/mathematical-constants

Comment: That wouldn't shorten the list a lot. I'd exclude only Numerical Analysis. The other fields are purely theoretical. Again, unless you are more specific about what aspects are you interested, there's really no way to point at a specific field.

Comment: Are you interested in formulas that includes the constant? Representation through integrals, series, limits, special functions, number theoretic functions? Are you interested in knowing if the number is irrational, trascendental, computable, normal?

Comment: @jjagmath := I'd answer Yes to your second and third questions. Specially, your third question even though I'd like both of them.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. It wasn't a yes or no question. I was asking in the second question which type of representation are you interested in? In the third question, which property of the number?

Comment: @jjagmath := My bad. I believe I'd particularly like to work on integral representations of $\gamma$ and also, finding out if it is irrational or not.

Comment: That would land in the Analysis field.

Comment: @jjagmath := So, you mean to say analytic number theory(because this also uses analysis as far as I know)? Or, do you mean just Real and Complex Analysis in general? And why not add you reply as an answer?

Comment: I mean Real Analysis. The constant do shows up in several formulas of Analytic Number Theory, but the emphasis there is never in the constant.

Comment: Simply look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function then dig into what you find interesting.